# How to reference constant in attribute in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I need to specify String constant as value of attribute:

```
<int:header name="importedFilename" />
```

here "importedFilename" should not be hardcoded but taken from f.e. from `Constants.IMPORTED_FILENAME_HEADER` static field. Is there a way to do it? "int" is Spring Integration namespace btw. Also it seems that there is no appropriate bean definition to replace `int:header` with - so I can't use `<bean class="Header">...`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
<util:constant id="importedFilenameHeader"
    static-field="your.package.Constants.IMPORTED_FILENAME_HEADER"/>
```

You should then be able to reference this by its id (`importedFilenameHeader`) to be used in your `<int:header>` element like so:

```
<int:header name="importedFilename" ref="importedFilenameHeader"/>
```

***EDIT:***

You should be able to do this using SpEL.  It is Spring's Expression Language, and it is available in 3.0 (maybe 2.5 also?).

I think you can go about doing this then:

```
<util:constant id="importedFilenameHeader"
    static-field="your.package.Constants.IMPORTED_FILENAME_HEADER"/>
<int:header name="#{importedFilenameHeader}" ... />
```

Spring should then evaluate this to be the value of the Constant `importedFilenameHeader` that we defined in the original part (which is also included in this example).

Here is some location information for getting the `util` namespace:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd">
```

Comment: I'm aware of `util:constant` element. When using it the question is: how to reference it in attribute so that it is interpreted as id/ref to bean, not the String itself? Simple `name="importedFilenameHeader"` and `name="#importedFilenameHeader"` do not work.

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how you can reference the constant for your header named `importedFilename`.

Comment: This is the point: I need to be able to configure name of header from static field, not the value.

Comment: @yozh:  Sorry, I was unable to get that from your question originally.  Not your fault, just a communication issue.  I have updated my answer based on your clarification.  Let me know if it works or not.

Answer (score 10):

```
<int:header name="#{T(com.example.Constants).IMPORTED_FILENAME_HEADER}" />
```

should work (see http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html#d0e11977).